# Upgrading apt packages gets stuck

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

When running `sudo apt upgrade` it gets stuck at:

```
Preparing to unpack .../00-linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic_5.4.0-90.101_amd64.deb ...
```

I killed the process and ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then I tried again but the same problem happend again. The package name that apt got stuck is named `linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic`

**Solved**:

The solution is to reboot **TWICE** in my case. When I posted this question I only rebooted one time but when rebooting again `apt` upgraded `linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic` successfully without getting stuck.